# Simple PHP syntax - How to get vSlider names to use post-ID

Tags: php

vSlider - in WordPress I'm using the function supplied in the FAQs:

`<?php if(function_exists('vslider')){ vslider('vslider_options'); } ?>`

And I'm trying to do this. So its knows to get the post-ID as its name. But its not working.

`<?php if(function_exists('vslider')){ vslider('<?php the_ID(); ?>'); } ?>`

Comment: Ugh - `the_ID()` is another one of those stupid Wordpress functions that prints to the screen rather than return a value.  Need to find the appropriate method to _return_ the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot nest `<?php ?>` inside an already open `<?php ?>`.  That is unsupported and syntactically invalid. Just call the function in place.

Apparently, `the_ID()` is one of those Wordpress functions which prints to the output buffer without returning its value.  To get the id *returned* where it can be useful in a function, use [`get_the_ID()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) instead.

```
<?php if(function_exists('vslider')){ vslider(get_the_ID()); } ?>
```

The syntax issue becomes more obvious when expressed as properly indented code.

```
<?php 
if (function_exists('vslider')){
  vslider(get_the_ID());
}
?>
```

Comment: Excellent. This absolutely worked first time. You were totally right about get_the_id. I did try that too but again my php syntax was out. Thank you so much. I would mark this up but apparently I have to be at 15...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by removing the php tags

```
 <?php if(function_exists('vslider')){ vslider('<?php the_ID(); ?>'); } ?>

should be 

<?php if(function_exists('vslider')){ vslider(the_ID()); } ?>
```

and your `the_ID()` function should return a string at the end